# Jenkins Git fetch referring to old commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating Jenkins CI flow for an angular 6 application. 
I created a Multi-Configuration project. And selected below values in the configuration:

**Source Code Management:**
  Git: Repo_URL
  Branches to build: */master
  Repository browser: Auto

**Build Triggers:**
  Gerrit event: checked

**Gerrit Trigger:**
  Choose a server: gerrit.*.com
  Trigger on: Patchset created
              Command Added Contains Reg Exp: [Rr][Ee][Vv][Ee][Rr][Ii][Ff][Yy]

**Dynamic Trigger Configuration:**
   Gerrit Project:
     Type: Plair Pattern: projName
   Branches:
     Type: Plair Pattern: master

**Build Environment:**
  Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH: NodeJS path
  npmrc file: system default

**Build:**
 Command:
    echo $PATH
    node --version
    npm --version
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    ng build

When I commit the code or when I do reverify, the build is getting triggered but it is fetching previous commit instead of the latest commit which is triggering the build.

Below is the build log:

```
10:55:56 Cloning the remote Git repository      
10:55:56 Cloning repository ssh://rmp-bot@***       
10:55:56  > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/application_name/Patchset-Sonar-CI-master # timeout=10          
10:55:56 Fetching upstream changes from ssh://rmp-bot@***             
10:55:56  > git --version # timeout=10        
10:55:56 using GIT_SSH to set credentials Gerrit ssh user              
10:55:56  > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://rmp-bot@***   +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*                           
10:55:57  > git config remote.origin.url ssh://rmp-bot@*** # timeout=10
10:55:57  > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10            
10:55:57  > git config remote.origin.url ssh://rmp-bot@*** # timeout=10           
10:55:57 Fetching upstream changes from ssh://rmp-bot@***        
10:55:57 using GIT_SSH to set credentials Gerrit ssh user               
10:55:57  > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://rmp-bot@***  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*                   
10:55:57  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10          
10:55:57  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10                
10:55:57 Checking out Revision fc96e9e083c368ff963114914fede303d885ae6a (refs/remotes/origin/master)           
10:55:57  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10                 
10:55:57  > git checkout -f fc96e9e083c368ff963114914fede303d885ae6a
```

The setup with different project type is working for other Applications Jenkins setup. Please let me know what went wrong in the above configuration.

I also tried adding Refspec: refs/changes/*:refs/changes/* & Name: origin in SCM -> Git -> Repositores. But still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by providing the proper value for Refspec: refs/changes/*:refs/changes/* in SCM -> Git -> Repositores.

Answer (score 1):

To resolves this problem, add the prefix "origin"  to the branch you want build. 
like this:

```
Branches to build: origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically caused by some caching in the workspace.

There are a few options to fix this.

1. Delete/clean the workspace before the git checkout phase. There is an option for this in the job configuration in Jenkins `Delete workspace before build starts`. This option is under "Build Environment" in a freestyle job.
2. As mkebri mentioned in their answer.. add the `origin/` prefix to the branch name. This tells git to use the `remote` branch.
3. In the additional behaviours option in the Git section of the job, you can add "Wipe out repository & force clone" which is similar to option one.
4. There are plugins available which can also do these things for you

Answer (score 0):

As mkebri said, editing projects Configure -> SCM -> Branches to Build helps. To build any branch, you can add:

```
origin/*
```